# Metadata changes in DIP not reflected in properties

Tags: managed-metadata, taxonomy, document-info-panel, dip

we have a problem with Managed Metadata and changes in Document Information panel in Word.

When a user changes a property in the DIP, the changes are not reflected in the documents properties after save. If you change it via "Edit properties", it is reflected both in properties and DIP, but if you do it the other way around, it is only reflected in the DIP. So the new value is showing in the DIP, but not in "View properties"-form. There is still the old value.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same problem in two document libraries in two different farms. All other fields worked fine in DIP except managed metadata fields.

I don't know what have caused this problem for these document libraries. Fixed by adding new dummy managed metadata column temporarily in the list and removing it afterwards.

http://alexbrassington.com/2013/04/29/managed-metadata-columns-fail-to-sync-between-sharepoint-and-client-applications/#comments